# Create pop() function stack implementation in C

Tags: c, char, stack, scanf, singly-linked-list

My program creates a stack of characters from user input, terminated by an asterisk. PopAll() works perfectly to pop every element one by one, but using pop() repeatedly doesn't. I don't understand how this is happening since popAll() just uses pop() under the hood.

Can anyone tell me what's going wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct NODE {
    char value;
    struct NODE *prev;
};

void push(char);
void pop();
void popAll();

int checkTerminator(char);

struct NODE *TOP = NULL;

int main()
{
    char input;
    
    while(checkTerminator(input) == 0){
        scanf("%c", &input);
        if(checkTerminator(input) == 0){
            push(input);
        }
    }
    
    printf("\nOutput:\n");

    // Doesn't pop three elements
    pop();
    pop();
    pop();

    // Succesfully pops all elements
    // popAll();

}

int checkTerminator(char value){
    switch(value){
        case '*':
            return 1;
        default:
            return 0;
    }
}

void push(char value){
    struct NODE *CURRENT = (struct NODE*) malloc(sizeof(struct NODE));

    CURRENT->value = value;
    CURRENT->prev = TOP;
    TOP = CURRENT;
}

void pop(){
    printf("%c", TOP->value);
    TOP = TOP->prev;
}

void popAll(){
    while(TOP != NULL){
        pop();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters the while loop has undefined behavior because the variable `input` was not initialized and has indeterminate value.

```
char input;

while(checkTerminator(input) == 0){
```

And you have to use the following format in the call of `scanf`

```
scanf(" %c", &input);
      ^^^^
```

Otherwise you will read white space characters as for example the new line character `'\n'`.

The function `pop` produces memory leaks because it does not free allocated nodes.

```
void pop(){
    printf("%c", TOP->value);
    TOP = TOP->prev;
}
```

The function `checkTerminator` can be written simpler. For example

```
int checkTerminator( char c )
{
    return c == '*';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from issues, pointed out by Vlad, I found this:

```
void pop(){
    printf("%c", TOP->value);
    TOP = TOP->prev;
}
```

You are not checking, if `TOP` is NULL or not. At the end, it becomes NULL, and you end up accessing NULL ponter, which will give you segmentation fault. (If you only call pop() a number of times).